# Как JS может узнать о появлении .php файлов на сервере?

Tags: php, javascript

Как `JS` из `DOM` может узнать о появлении `.php` файлов на сервере ?

Через `setInterval` делать `AJAX` запросы ?

- Это работает в моём случае, но копится куча `404 ошибок` когда файла нет.

Может быть есть более правильный способ уведомить `JS` о появлении файлов ?

Comment: 1. websockets
2. А почему бы не делать запрос через setInterval не к файлу, а к чему-то, что вернет файл или None, если файла нет?

Comment: @Axenow к чему-то , это к чему ?

Comment: Сначала не понял ваш комментарий. Создать еще один route, который будет проверять наличие файла для конкретного пользователя. Просто если вы приведете пример поведения программы, то я смогу помочь чуть лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если известны имена php-файлов, которые должны появиться на сервере, то через ajax делается запрос к следующему php-файлу:

```
<?php
   $filename = "test.php"; // имя файла, появление которого отслеживается
   //$filename = $_GET["filename"]; // это строка, если вдруг передавать имя файла из ajax-запроса
                                    // методом GET с параметром filename, например, 
                                    // http://www.site.ru/check_file.php?filename=test.php
                                    // Тогда первая строка $filename = "test.php" не нужна
   if (file_exists($filename)) {
       echo "exists";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "not exists";
   }
?>
```

Файлы будут проверяться в том же каталоге, что и вызываемый скрипт.
В ответ на ajax-запрос придет либо "exists" (если файл существует), либо "not exists" (если файл НЕ существует). Либо формировать json-ответ вместо обычного текста "exists" и "not exists".

Comment: Ещё не вчитывался, но на всякий спрошу, `$filename = $_GET["filename"];` - это в том случае если название знает только `JS` и как бы записать его в переменную `PHP` - верно ?

Comment: Да, именно так. Т.е. $_GET["filename"] читает значение переменной "filename" после знака "равно" в ссылке http://www.site.ru/check_file.php?filename=test.php, которую (ссылку) уже можно формировать средствами JS. Если будет POST-Ajax-запрос, тогда вместо $_GET использовать $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какая предполагается нагрузка и смотря какая конечная цель. Самое простое - AJAX-запрос. Делай запрос на некий роут, который будет проверять `file_exists()` и возвращать результат в JSON. Можно веб-сокеты, да, но придётся посидеть поизучать.